# Python- How do I update an index of a for loop that iterates over lines in a file?

Tags: python, indexing, variable-assignment

Using a for loop, I'm iterating over the lines in a file. Given this line:

```
line= [ ‘641', '"Tornadus', ' (Incarnate Form)"', '"Flying"', '""', '5', '"TRUE"']
```

I need to reformat index [6] from '"TRUE"' to the boolean True.

Full expected output: d={'Tornadus, (Incarnate Form)': (641, 'Flying', None, 5, True}

I used:

```
if "T" in line[6]:  # format legendary if TRUE
    line[6] = True
```

But I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "tester5p.py", line 305, in test_read_info_file_05
>   self.assertEqual(read_info_file(DATAFILE),info_db5())File "/Users/kgreenwo/Desktop/student.py", line 52, in read_info_file
>       line[5] = False
>
> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

How can I assign it WITHIN the for loop?

To see my full code:

```
def read_info_file(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')  # open file in read mode
    d = {}  # intitialze as empty
    count = 0  # helps to skip first line
    key = ""
    for line in f:  # get each line from file
        if count != 0:  # skip first line
        # 1___________________________________________open file,read, skip 1st line
            id_num = int(line[0])  # make id an integer
        # 2________________________________________________
            if ',' in line[1]:  # two parts to fullname, changes indexes
                part1 = line[1].strip('"')  # get format first part of name
                part2 = line[2].strip()  # get format second part of name
            # 3______________
                fullname = part1 + part2
                key = fullname
            # 4______________
                type1 = line[3].strip('"')
            # 5--------------
                if line[4] == "":  # check if there is not a second type
                    type2 = None  # correct format
                else:  # is a second type
                    type2 = line[4].strip('"')  # format second type
            # 6______________

                generation = line[5]  # format generation
            # 7_____________
                if "T" in line[6]:  # format legendary if TRUE
                    line[6] = True
                    legendary = line[6]
                else:  # format legendary if FALSE
                    line[6] = False
                    legendary = line[6]

            # 8______________________________________________one part to name
            else:  # one part to name
                fullname = line[1].strip('"')
            # 9______________
                type1 = line[2].strip('"')
            # 10_____________
                if line[3] == "":  # if no second type
                    type2 = None
                else:
                    type2 = line[3].strip('"')  # there is a second type
            # 11_____________
                generation = line[4]  # format generation
            # 12_____________
                if "T" in line[5]:  # format legendary if TRUE
                    line[5] = True
                    legendary = line[5]
                else:  # formmat Legendary if False
                    line[5] = False
                    legendary = line[5]

            value = (id_num, type1, type2, generation, legendary)
            d.update([(key, value)])
        count += 1
    return d
```

> Reproducible example:
>   input: (don't forget to skip first line!)

```
info_file1 = '''"ID","Name","Type 1","Type 2","Generation","Legendary"
1,"Bulbasaur","Grass","Poison",1,"FALSE"
```

> Output:
>           d={'Bulbasaur':(1,'Grass','Poison',1,False)}

Comment: You need to provide a *reproducible example*. Your example of `line` is not valid Python, and it seems you mean to make it a list, in which case, it would not throw that error.

Comment: I don't know if it's because you typed it in or not, but the first quote mark " ' " is a different symbol.  When I copy your above code into the python interpreter, it says everything after "641'" is a string.

Comment: I added my full code so that you can see what I'm doing. It is commented for clarification. The list of the line is created when I used read(). Everything in that list becomes a string. I have to convert the necessary elements to the output that I need.

Comment: I also added my needed output. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that `line` is a `str`, since it is iterating over a file-handler. Indexing into a string gives the *character* at that position, e.g.`"hello"[1] == 'e'`. You can't assign to a string. I think you want to split your line on commas... And you have *yet to provide a reproducible example*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga added the example

Comment: Right, as I suspected, you are working with some value-delimited file, i.e. a csv, but when you iterate over that file, line by line, `line` is a **string**. When you index into a string you index into the characters, and you can't assign to a string. You are assuming that `line` is a list of strings based on the delimiter in your file...

Comment: So is there no way to get around that? I don't want to change my whole code. I was trying to use readlines() and split at the commas but it created all sorts of chaos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of reassigning it, I just did this and it worked:

```
if "T" in line[6]:  # format legendary if TRUE
    legendary = True
else:  # format legendary if FALSE
    legendary = False
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite unclear from your example, but my thoughts go to:

```
for line in f:
    line = line.split(',')
```

Now you can mess with indexes and see whether you have more errors.
And if you use:

```
if "T" in line[6]:  # format legendary if TRUE
    line[6] = True
```

It will work.

Comment: Even using your method returns : ['641', '"Tornadus', ' (Incarnate Form)"', '"Flying"', '""', '5', '"TRUE"']

Answer (score 1):

Your input file looks like a [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file. If it is, what you want is pretty easy.

Let's suppose your input file is literally this:

**Input_file-43644346.txt**

```
info_file1 = '''"ID","Name","Type 1","Type 2","Generation","Legendary"
1,"Bulbasaur","Grass","Poison",1,"FALSE"
641,"Tornadus', ' (Incarnate Form)","Flying",,5,"TRUE"
```

You could do something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv

input_file_name = "Input_file-43644346.txt"

with open(input_file_name, newline='') as input_file:
    next(input_file)        # skip first line
    record_extractor = csv.reader(input_file)
    d = {}
    for row in record_extractor:
        key = row[1].strip()
        row_truth = row[5] == "TRUE"        # simplifying the boolean retrieving
        # Using conditional expressions
        row_second_type = row[3].strip() if row[3] else None   
        output_row = (row[0], row[2], row_second_type, row[4], row_truth)
        d[key] = output_row

print("d=", d)
```

Here are some key points of this solution:

- This example is in Python 3's syntax
- Using `with` makes sure that the input file is closed timely
- Since a file object is also an iterator, you can skip the first line by using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).
- [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)  will give you a tuple containing the information from a row. It will process quoted string like you would expect.
- The expression `row[5] == "TRUE"` will yield a boolean expression. You don't need to use an `if` statement.
- An empty string is equivalent to False. Any other string is True.
- [Conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator) can be used to change an empty string to `None` like you wanted.
- [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) is useful if you already have a dictionary or a list of tuples you want to use its values to update an dictionary but you are better off using `d[key] = value`

---

But my guess is that your file is more like that:

**Input_file-43644346b.txt**

```
"ID","Name","Type 1","Type 2","Generation","Legendary"
1,"Bulbasaur","Grass","Poison",1,"FALSE"
641,"Tornadus', ' (Incarnate Form)","Flying",,5,"TRUE"
```

You can then use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to read your data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv

input_file_name = "Input_file-43644346b.txt"

with open(input_file_name, newline='') as input_file:
    record_extractor = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    d = {}
    for row in record_extractor:
        key = row["Name"].strip()
        row_truth = row["Legendary"] == "TRUE"
        row_second_type = row["Type 2"].strip() if row["Type 2"] else None
        output_row = (row["ID"], row["Type 1"],
                      row_second_type, row["Generation"], row_truth)
        d[key] = output_row

print("d=", d)
```

That enables you to use "column" names to identify different parts of each row

---

You can simplify even more your code by using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) comprehension:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv

input_file_name = "Input_file-43644346.txt"

with open(input_file_name, newline='') as input_file:
    next(input_file)        # skip first line
    record_extractor = csv.reader(input_file)
    d = { row[1]: (row[0],
                   row[2],
                   row[3].strip() if row[3] else None,
                   row[4],
                   row[5] == "TRUE")
          for row in record_extractor }

print("d=", d)
```